# When should scientific disciplines be capitalized?

Tags: capitalization, science

When writing motivation letters like SoP, or any other formal text, I don't know whether I have to capitalize sciences or areas of research.

For example:

> - I have been introduced to Neuroscience.
> - I have been introduced to neuroscience.

Are there any criteria for capitalization?

Comment: Can you explain why you believe they would be capitalized, or can you provide examples where they are?

Comment: @choster, I have to admit now that I try to find one incidence on web about it I cannot find any capitalised term. Thanks.

Comment: Please also search through past questions. There are some relevant to this.

Comment: When they're a shortened form of a department. "I must get this sample over to Immunology." "The DI has just been in touch with Pathology."

Answer (score 1):

Never should scientific disciplines be capitalized.

Source: dictionaries

> Are there any criteria for capitalization?

Just because it's a mass noun (or a non-count noun) doesn't mean you can freely capitalize it. Please don't confuse a mass noun with a proper noun, which should generally be capitalized.

Answer (score -2):

When they are specific scientific disciplines. Words can also be used otherwise.
"This is not rocket science."
"I did not study Rocket Science."

Comment: Will the downvoting pundit please elaborate, thanks.

Comment: Upvoted to protest "shadow shooters"

Comment: -1 because 1. 'Rocket science' in your 1st example isn't used as a scientific discipline but as a metaphor. 2. Even when used as a scientific discipline as in your 2nd example, it should never be capitalized for reasons set forth in my answer.